# Firebase config variables are not available error with deploying functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

When I am deploying Firebase functions without

```
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
```

Firebase logs

> Error: The default Firebase app does not exist. Make sure you call
>   initializeApp() before using any of the Firebase services.

But if I add that line I get error on deploy.

```
>firebase deploy --only functions
```

Error:

> Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers. Please
>   ensure you have the latest firebase-functions SDK by running "npm i
>   --save firebase-functions@latest" inside your functions folder.
>
> Error: Firebase config variables are not available. Please use the
>   latest version of the Firebase CLI to deploy this function.

I already did `npm i --save firebase-functions@latest` which haven't done anything. I am stuck and can't do anything right now because of this... I am down for any reinstalls if they could help just tell me some steps or hints and I would seek for the rest.

---

NPM and NodeJS versions are:

```
node -v
v8.9.1
npm -v
5.6.0
```

**Edit.** Installation with admin rights:

```
npm i --save firebase-functions@latest
npm WARN firebase-functions@0.8.1 requires a peer of firebase-admin@~5.8.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! path C:\Users\Telion\firebaseApps\project-name\functions\node_modules\firebase-admin\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\abbrev
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\Telion\firebaseApps\project-name\functions\node_modules\firebase-admin\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\abbrev' -> 'C:\Users\Telion\firebaseApps\project-name\functions\node_modules\firebase-admin\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\.abbrev.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

It actually appeared I was on npm version 5.5.1 but even after the update to 5.6.0 I got the exact same error.

Comment: Did you run `npm i --save firebase-functions@latest` with admin privileges?

Comment: @Rosário Pereira Fernandes actually no, I updated the question with additional information about this.

Comment: Please try running `npm install -g firebase-tools` with admin privileges. This should update the whole Firebase CLI

Comment: @Rosário Pereira Fernandes thx a lot! I couldn't do anything for like 1.5 weeks because of this and you fixed that in a day. Thank you.

Comment: Installing older version `npm install -g firebase-tools@3.16.0` solved this for me.

Answer (score 6):

There was a breaking change introduced in `firebase-tools@3.17.x` which requires your project to upgrade `firebase-functions` to the latest version.

However, `firebase-functions@latest` also requires `firebase-admin@latest` (at the time of writing this answer `firebase-admin@5.11.0`. Once all packages are upgraded, this problem should be solved.

Another alternative is to downgrade your global `firebase-tools` to `3.16.0`, which lets you use older `firebase-functions` and `firebase-admin` packages.

Answer (score 1):

**I ran into the same issue in Ubuntu and this is how i solved it**

Install firebase using : `sudo npm install -g firebase-tools`

Also make sure you launch using admin privileges e.g to login

```
sudo firebase login
```

Comment: Running everything with ample rights looks a security nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to update the node to at least 8.15.x. That detail is shown in the message.

Once I intalled that I had to do a `firebase login` command and after that you can run the `firebase init hosting`

Previously I was getting the error on `firebase init hosting` but after that node update, it went away.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked for firebase-tools6.9.2. 
The firebase-tools3.16.0  is completely depricated.